# How to make my CustomButton stretch and shrink like a ElevatedButton

Tags: flutter

Does someone know why my `CustomButton` keeps stretching while the `ElevatedButton` doesn't. It looks like both components are using similar constraints..

- Elevated button: 64.0<=w<=Infinity, h=48.0
- Custom button: 32.0<=w<=Infinity, h=32.0

Only the elevated button doesn't stretch when `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` is disabled only my custom button does.

I'm trying to get my custom button's width to stretch when `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch` is set and to shrink when it is not set.

Example code: https://dartpad.dev/?id=1beeb8305313f7c52f29d337c4dca4a7

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the ElevatedButton widget is using a ConstrainedBox to set the constraints on its child, while your CustomButton widget is not. The ConstrainedBox widget enforces the given constraints on its child, so the child will not be able to exceed those constraints.

To fix this, you can wrap your CustomButton widget in a ConstrainedBox and set the desired constraints on it. For example:

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 32.0, minHeight: 32.0),
  child: CustomButton(...),
)
```

This should prevent the CustomButton from stretching beyond the given constraints.

Comment: Hi Joe, thanks for your comment! This is not really workable.. I'm looking for a solution to use the `CustomButton` without having to wrap ik with a `ConstrainedBox` every time I use it. Also the first child of the `CustomButton` is a `Container` where the constraints are already set. I'm trying to get the same behaviour for both buttons in the DartPad example.